# C++ passing object to function by refrence, its constructor get called

Tags: c++

I'm trying to figure out how to use multiple files properly. I made a class in the header file. Then a cpp file that included that header file and implemented everything with Stage::Stage(){} etc. I also made a class called Display that has no default constructor, but requires 2 integer arguments. I made a function in Stage class:

```
Stage::Stage (Display &display_){
    display = display_;
}
```

But it causes an error "no matching function for call to 'Display::Display()'"
Which is true, it doesn't exist, but it shouldnt need to exist. I'm not trying to create a new Display object here, I'm trying to pass an existing one to the Stage object. (I'm using Dev C++)

Comment: `display = display_;` means to call the assignment operator of `display`. You didn't say what `display` is, but presumably it is a member variable of `Stage`, which must already have been constructed by this point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Stage` constructor must default-initialize `display` before executing the body of the constructor. All class members must be constructed before executing the body of the class's constructor. No exceptions. The shown code, therefore, attempts to default-construct `display` before using the assignment operator on it.

Since `Display` does not have a default constructor, this fails, hence the complaint from your compiler that there is no defualt constructor.

In this situation you must explicitly construct `display` in the initialization section of the constructor:

```
Stage::Stage (Display &display_) : display{display_}
{
}
```

or, pre-C++11:

```
Stage::Stage (Display &display_) : display(display_)
{
}
```

This explicitly constructs the `display` member right from the beginning, presumably using its copy-constructor.